# Removing buttons from the editor

Tags: tinymce

I have this nice little function to remove buttons from the tinyMCE editor in WordPress, so far I've been able to remove most of the ones I need to.

```
function custom_disable_mce_buttons( $opt ) {
    $opt['theme_advanced_disable'] = 'justifyfull,forecolor,removeformat,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyleft,charmap,indent,outdent,undo, redo';
    return $opt;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'custom_disable_mce_buttons');
```

The button control list can be found here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:Buttons/controls

The problem is, there's a few more ones I'd like to remove, like the spellchecker and the 'insert more tag', but I can't find documentation anywhere of the codes/names for these buttons to remove them.

Any got any info on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wp_more` - insert more button,

`spellchecker` - spellchecker button

I've tried it with your code on WP 3.5.1 and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Can you direct me towards any documentation of this or where you found it?

Comment: Well, I checked it in WP sources :)

Comment: You can also know the names by inspecting the button and checking the class. If you have mce-i-spellchecker the button name is spellchecker.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to remove the *Spellchecker* and the *Insert More Tag* buttons by adding:

```
spellchecker, wp_more
```

to your `$opt['theme_advanced_disable']` comma-seperated string.

On my install I have these options:

```
[theme_advanced_buttons1] => bold,italic,strikethrough,bullist,numlist,blockquote,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,link,unlink,wp_more,spellchecker,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv,separator

[theme_advanced_buttons2] => formatselect,underline,justifyfull,forecolor,pastetext,pasteword,removeformat,charmap,outdent,indent,undo,redo,wp_help
```

Here is the list:

```
bold,
italic,
strikethrough,
bullist,
numlist,
blockquote,
justifyleft,
justifycenter,
justifyright,
link,
unlink,
wp_more,
spellchecker,
wp_fullscreen,
wp_adv,
separator,
```

and

```
formatselect,
underline,
justifyfull,
forecolor,
pastetext,
pasteword,
removeformat,
charmap,
outdent,
indent,
undo,
redo,
wp_help
```

Comment: Note: `justifyleft, justifycenter, justifyright` changed to `alignleft, aligncenter, alignright`

Comment: Thanks for the update and feel free to update the answer if you see some outdated info @Sisir

Answer (score 5):

```
add_filter("mce_buttons", "tinymce_editor_buttons", 99); //targets the first line
add_filter("mce_buttons_2", "tinymce_editor_buttons_second_row", 99); //targets the second line

function tinymce_editor_buttons($buttons) {
return array(
    "undo", 
    "redo", 
    "separator",
    "bold", 
    "italic", 
    "underline", 
    "strikethrough", 
    //"separator",
    //"bullist", 
    //"separator",
    //add more here...
    );
}

function tinymce_editor_buttons_second_row($buttons) {
   //return an empty array to remove this line
    return array();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I am trying to show the code button. I tried code-sample and code.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle you're welcome. Hope you got it to work.

Comment: Hi. At the moment I can’t get code button to show. Tried code, sample-code. Next I will try code-sample but I have to check on pc. The tablet shows restricted buttons it seems.

Comment: In the end I sorted it by installing the TinyMCE Advanced plugin.