# Overriding TinyMCE buttons - Justify button shortcodes not working

Tags: tinymce

**Problem**

I'm trying to customise the TinyMCE text editor. Several of the common options for overruling Tiny MCE didn't seem to work for me. So instead I overwrote the functions in my functions file:

```
function tinymce_editor_buttons($buttons) {
        return array(
                "justifyleft",
                "justifycenter",
                "justifyright",
                "bold",
                "italic", 
                "underline",
                "bullist",
                "numlist",
                "link",
                "hr",
                "undo", 
                "redo", 
                "separator",
                "pastetext",
                "removeformat",
                "formatselect",
                "styleselect",
                );
        }
add_filter("mce_buttons", "tinymce_editor_buttons", 99);

function tinymce_editor_buttons_second_row($buttons) {
   //return an empty array to remove this line
    return array();
}
add_filter("mce_buttons_2", "tinymce_editor_buttons_second_row", 99);
```

This works great except for the justify functions and separator, which don't appear.

This [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103347/removing-buttons-from-the-editor) lists all the shortcodes, so I think I have the correct codes, and removing and adding other options works, however these two don't.

Why would these options not appear when all the others do?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using button references to version 3 of TinyMCE.  Beginning in WordPress version 3.9; TinyMCE 4 is being used.

Check [this page](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php), then click the "View Source" tab to see the new button names.

Working from your array above:

```
TinyMCE 3        TinyMCE 4
justifyleft   => alignleft
justifycenter => aligncenter
justifyright  => alignright
```

As far as I know, the `separator` button has been removed from WordPress core.  I believe they removed the css rules which allowed the separator previously.  This [WordPress Trac Ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23366) may explain more.